# Java : How to use Child List to filter parent List using lambda functions?

Tags: java, lambda, xsd, filtering

Lists are generated from schema.

Currently, I have ObjectList A which contains (elements and couple of child object list)
Child list contains(elements)

Instance: ObjectList A has {String ABC, String XYZ , ObjectList B (contains String A1, String A2 and so on), String xxx)

I want to perform some operation on elements of List A. I am using predicates and using filter options.

For example, Predicate k = x-> some if conditions

ListA.stream().filter(k).collections(to.list)   (works)

---

But when I want to run some conditions on elements of child ObjectList B and use it to filter Parent ObjectList A, I am not able to. Keep in mind ObjectList B is child-list of ObjectList A.
The above method does not work.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please take some time to create a [mcve], and use clear language. Formatting goes a long way.

Comment: There are ambiguities and typos in your question. Please review.

Comment: You shouldn't have mixed types in a `List`. All objects in a `List` needs to have a common type that makes sense. `List<String>` and `List<List<String>>` are entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

(A is object)

List list1= mapping to the list;

```
      List<A> filteredlist = list1.stream().filter(e ->
                            e.getNames().getSalaries().stream().anyMatch(Predicate)
                    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Than you can use the filtered list to remove from main list.
list1.removeall(filteredlist);

Answer (score 0):

If a list type is string like`List<string>`
It should contain only string.. U can't add another list.. So you can perform filter operation on it.
Or
If you have `list<list<String>>` iterate one more time to perform any operations